# Can't understand the error is existing

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers

Error:

```
temp:-1: 6
p[0]: 6
loop:p[0]: 6
temp:0: 5
p[1]: 5
loop:p[1]: 5
temp:1: 4
p[2]: 4
loop:p[2]: 4
temp:2: 7
p[3]: 7
loop:p[3]: 7
temp:3: 9
p[4]: 9
loop:p[4]: 9
temp:4: 8
p[5]: 8
loop:p[5]: 8
temp:5: 4
temp:5: 9
temp:5: 0
p[6]: 0
loop:p[6]: 0
temp:6: 1
p[7]: 1
loop:p[7]: 1
temp:7: 2
p[8]: 2
loop:p[8]: 2
temp:8: 3
p[9]: 3
loop:p[9]: 3
temp:9: 4
temp:9: 1
temp:9: 12
increasing size 0: 6
increasing size 1: 5
increasing size 2: 4
increasing size 3: 7
increasing size 4: 9
increasing size 5: 8
increasing size 6: 0
increasing size 7: 1
increasing size 8: 2
increasing size 9: 3
```

```
a.out(58583,0x7fffb423c3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff53e9fb00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I can't understand this.

Following is the code I'm running.Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int insert_in(int* p,int index, int* size, int item);
void swap(int* a, int* b);
void bubble_sort(int a[], int size);

int main( int argc, char* argv[]){

    int size=10;
    int index=-1;
    int p[size];
    int temp;
    int i;
    int duplicate=0;

    scanf("%d",&temp);
    //insert_in(p,index,&size,temp);
    printf("temp:%d: %d\n",index,temp);
    while(temp!=-1){
        duplicate=0;
        for(i=0;i<=index;i++){

            if(p[i]==temp){
                duplicate=1;
                break;
            }

        }

        if(duplicate!=1){
            index++;
            insert_in(p,index,&size,temp);
            printf("loop:p[%d]: %d\n",index,p[index]);
        }

        scanf("%d",&temp);
        printf("temp:%d: %d\n",index,temp);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= index; i++) {

        printf("before p[%d]: %d\n",i, p[i]);
    }

    bubble_sort(p,index+1);

    for (i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}

void bubble_sort(int a[], int size) {
    int n;
    int i;
    for (n = 0; n < size - 1; n++) {
        for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                swap(&a[i], &a[i + 1]); 
            }
        }
    }

}

void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int insert_in(int* p,int index, int* size, int item){
    int* temp=NULL;
    int i=0;
    if(index>=(*size)){

        temp=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*size)*2);
        if(temp==NULL){
            printf("unable to allocate memory");
            return 0;
        }

        for( i=0;i<(*size);i++){

            temp[i]=p[i];
            printf("increasing size %d: %d\n",i,p[i]);

        }
        free(p);
        p=temp;
        (*size)*=2;
        printf("size %d: %d\n",i,*size);
    }

    p[index]=item;
    printf("p[%d]: %d\n",index,p[index]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you `free`ing `p`? You don't appear to have allocated it using `new`. Do you even initialize it anywhere?

Comment: You already seem to know how to *emulate pass by reference in C* (with the `size` argument to the `insert_in` function). Now think about that for the `p` argument of the same function.

Comment: If you have a memory management issue, run your code through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.com).

Comment: Oh and you should probably do some research about the [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function.

Comment: Array can not be `free`.

Comment: Okay if i dont free it, then there appears to be some garbage value at p[10]. let me give you that code. thanks for helping!

Comment: size 10: 20
p[10]: 12
loop:p[10]: 361824841

Comment: even though inside the insert_in function p[10]=12 in the main function p[10] becomes a random number. Is it becoming a different pointer to the array?

Comment: Have you done as it says and set a breakpoint on malloc_error? If not, do so and see if you can solve your own problem. If not, add your results to your question.

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/iVznCy)

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `printf("unable to allocate memory");`  error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from system function, also output the related text from the OS.  Suggest: `perror( "malloc failed" );` as that handles all the requirements

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) insert appropriate space after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, around C operators.

Comment: when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, the use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the logic in `main()` fails to inform the user that entering `-1` is necessary to exit the input loop

Comment: in the posted code, if the call to `malloc()` fails, then might as well cleanup and exit the program, because this is an unrecoverable error

Comment: regarding: `free(p);
        p=temp;`  must not pass `p` to `free()`, because the original declaration of `p`, in `main()` is an array on the stack, NOT a pointer;.   Note: to change where a pointer points, in a sub function, the pointer must be passed as `**p` and all references need to reflect the `**` typing

Comment: a lot of the logic in the function: `insert_in()` can be eliminated by using the function: `realloc()` rather than the function: `malloc()`

Comment: in C, an array index can be from 0 through (number of elements in array -1).  Using 'p[10]' is accessing just beyond the end of the array.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest initialize `size` to 0 and declare `p` as `int *p = NULL;